# Eclipse Indigo doesn't include dependencies in jar folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, dependencies

I am using maven and external jars as an output from other project. When 
I build the project to create one jar, dependencies are not added. I want dependencies to be added.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>Generic.Demo</groupId>
      <artifactId>Generic.Demo</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.12</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
        </dependencies>
      </dependencyManagement>
      <modules></modules>
    </project>
```

This is how my pom.xml file looks like.. there is no build/plugins section to add

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Then add the build/plugins sections.

Comment: You need to read about Maven a bit before you ask any questions like that. Start with the free books at http://sonatype.com/Support/Books .. have a look at Maven by Example.

Answer (score 2):

Use maven assembly plugin with the built-in descriptor `jar-with-dependencies`

In your pom.xml add the following plugin to your build/plugins section:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
      </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
  <execution>
    <id>build-package</id>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>single</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
 </plugin>
```

Have a look at their website for all the crunchy details.

Comment: Thank you Guillaume Polet for replying. can you please explain where to use and how to use that descriptor.

Comment: Hi @Guillaume Polet. I tried as you explained but still result is the same.

Comment: Have you bound the goal to a phase? I just edited my answer and added an example of that. Then run `mvn package` and you should get what you want